# AndroidX - Program type already present: androidx.annotation.BoolRes

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to migrate my current project today to AndroidX using the "Refactor - > Migrate to AndroidX" option in Android Studio and whenever I try to compile my application, I receive a

> Program type already present: androidx.annotation.BoolRes
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: androidx.annotation.BoolRes","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>   :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

I used `./gradlew app:dependencies` to fetch my list of dependencies, but it seems a lot of libraries are using the new `androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0` dependency.

```
//Android
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayout"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidX"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidX"
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"

//Material
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material"

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle"

//Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the renderscript api in my build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    renderscriptTargetApi 28
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

Removing the `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled` and `renderscriptTargetApi` from the block seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't happen to me during migration. But I run the app in debug mode and without stopping the debug, run the app without debug (Clicked the run app button in android studio).

I need to Clean the project (Build->Clean Project) to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"
```

I think the problem is with this dependency, try to upgrade and check whether the problem is solved or not. You can try this if it works:-

```
androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha3
```

If it doesn't try to upgrade the dependency.

Comment: I know the problem is with that dependency. 1.0.0 is the latest version. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.annotation/annotation?repo=google

Comment: I did - no luck

Comment: ok, this is really strange, trying other version mentioned in your link ?

Answer (score 1):

Just disable renderscriptSupportModeEnabled and you will get your code compiled.
It is disabled by default so you can just remove the below line from your build.gradle file.

```
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled = true
```

Note: Above flag will be required if you gives support API level < 19.