# Problem while migration support library to androidx

Tags: android, migration, androidx

I just started a new project and migrated it to AndroidX, then I get the error below. I checked some solutions such as resolutionstrategy over annotations and exluding package but none of them worked for me.

My targetSdkVersion is 28, minSdkVersion is 16, buildToolsVersion 28.0.2 and androidX version is 1.0.0

`The error is Program type already present: androidx.annotation.BoolRes`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.mobil"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        renderscriptTargetApi rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    //TODO Signing Config

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            testCoverageEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //TODO Signing Config
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //MultiDex
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //AndroidX
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.ext.androidX"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:$rootProject.ext.androidX"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.ext.androidXConstraintLayout"

}
```

Comment: renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true is the reason of the problem. When I removed this line build is successful. Now the problem is how can I use with renderscriptSupportModeEnabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidX - Program type already present: androidx.annotation.BoolRes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533779/androidx-program-type-already-present-androidx-annotation-boolres)